# Error: 'System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I understand this question has been asked before but I'm finding it difficult to find an answer to my question. We do mass inserts of records each week and to prevent duplicates I need to check each insert.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger PreventDuplicates on Arrear__c (before insert) {
    String setMemberNumber;
    Id setId;
    List<Arrear__c> allArrears = new List<Arrear__c>();
    List<Arrear__c> updateArrear = new List<Arrear__c>();

    for(Arrear__c arrear : Trigger.new) {
        if(arrear.Member_Number__c != '') {
            setMemberNumber = arrear.Member_Number__c;
        }

        system.debug('Member Number' + setMemberNumber);
        allArrears = [Select Id, Member_Number__c,Name From Arrear__c where (Member_Number__c =: setMemberNumber) AND (Reason__c =: '') AND (Days_In_Arrears__c > 30)];
        system.debug(allArrears);

        for(Arrear__c arr: allArrears) {
            Arrear__c tempArr = new Arrear__c();
            tempArr = arr;
            tempArr.Reason__c = 'No Contact';
            updateArrear.add(tempArr); 
        }  
    }
    update updateArrear;
}
```

As the question mentions I'm getting a SOQL limit error. How am I able to avoid this error while still checking each record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a query in a loop, which is why you're getting the error when you upload a large number of records at once. You have a few minor other errors as well.

## There Are No Empty Strings

```
if(arrear.Member_Number__c != '') {
```

This will always return true, because string values will either be null or a non-empty string when they're initialized.

## Query In A Loop

You can't query inside a loop, because you'll hit governor limits. Instead, aggregate the values to search for, query those records, create a Map, and then process the results. Something like this:

```
trigger PreventDuplicates on Arrear__c (before insert) {
    Set<String> memberNumbers = new Set<String>();
    for(Arrear__c arrear: Trigger.new) {
        memberNumbers.add(arrear.Member_Number__c);
    }
    memberNumbers.remove(null);
    if(memberNumbers.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Arrear__c[] oldArrears = [select id from arrear__c where member_number__c = :membernumbers and reason__c = null and days_in_arrear__c > 30];
    for(Arrear__c arrear: oldArrears) {
        arrear.Reason__c = 'No Contact';
    }
    update oldArrears;
}
```

Note that this wouldn't prevent duplicates, nor can you both prevent duplicates *and* affect the database, so you'll have to determine how you want to proceed.